# Batch convert DDS file to DDS without mipmaps

Tags: bash, scripting, batch-processing, gimp, dds-format

I have a Mount & Blade: Warband mod called 1257 AD. The mod itself is great, but all the textures have to be resaved to remove mipmaps from dds files, to remove glitches on GNU/Linux. And of course, I could do this manually, but it will took a lot of time(over 2000 textures), and is there any way for gimp to just open and save the file without mipmaps.
Also, last time I wanted to do this I used loop with Imagemagicks convert, but it kept mipmaps. So how do I do this kind of convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the 'define' dds:mipmaps if you don't want to keep the mipmaps. Setting it to zero will disable the writing of mipmaps.

```
convert input.dds -define dds:mipmaps=0 output.dds
```

You can find a list of all dds defines here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php.

Comment: for x in *.dds;do convert "$x" -define dds:mipmaps=0 convert/"$x";done  
I think that should do it, keeping old files for the sake of if something goes wrong.

Comment: alternatively: find -type f -name "*.dds" | xargs -I{} convert {} -define dds:mipmaps=0 {}

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert them in place, use ImageMagick's `mogrify`, which is basically `convert` but does things in-place.

**Using `mogrify` has the potential to irreversibly corrupt your images, so use it wisely and avoid using long strung-out `convert`-like command lines (use simple commands).**

```
find . -type f -name "*.DDS" | xargs -L1 -I{} mogrify -define dds:mipmaps=0 "{}"
```

If you're sure you don't have spaces in your pathnames and you want a bit of a speed increase, then just do

```
find . -type f -name "*.DDS" | xargs mogrify -define dds:mipmaps=0
```