# How to avoid creating mipmaps for dds using python Wand?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, wand, dds-format

#### Env:

python - 3.6.6
[Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/) - 0.5.7

#### Code example:

Part of [this file](https://github.com/Yuriy-Leonov/pyglet_dds_power_of_two/blob/master/manage_files/create_files_from_png.py)

```
from wand import image

with image.Image(filename='example_32_on_32_px.png') as img:
    img.compression = 'dxt3'
    img.save(filename='output.dds')
```

It will produce `output.dds` which contains 5 mipmaps (16px, 8px, 4px, 2px, 1px).

I found CLI example for [ImageMagic](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) how to disable creation of mipmaps for output dds files -> [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28243024/4436022)
But I need to do same using python and Wand.

#### Question:

How to prevent / avoid / disable / delete mipmaps in output file using `Wand` library and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `Image.options` dict to set the property.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='example_32_on_32_px.png') as img:
    img.options['dds:mipmaps'] = '0'
    img.compression = 'dxt3'
    img.save(filename='output.dds')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/dds.c](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/dds.c) I found following: `option=GetImageOption(image_info,"dds:mipmaps");`

So solution of my quiestion was quite simple:

```
from wand import image

with image.Image(filename='example_32_on_32_px.png') as img:
    img.compression = 'dxt3'
    image.library.MagickSetOption(img.wand, b'dds:mipmaps', b'0')
    img.save(filename='output.dds')
```

If set `b'1'` instead of `b'0'` output file will contain only 1 mipmap (16px).